# Youtube Data API returns quota exceeded error but my quota is 0

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, youtube-data-api, jupyter-lab

I've been using JupyterLab to take notes in class, we making simple calls with the youtube api and I was the only person that kept getting this error. For reference this is the code that causes the error

```
request = youtube.search().list(
        part="snippet",
        maxResults=5,
        q="pewdiepie",
        type="channel"
    )
response = request.execute()
response
```

and this is the error message

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
HttpError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[7], line 7
      1 request = youtube.search().list(
      2         part="snippet",
      3         maxResults=5,
      4         q="pewdiepie",
      5         type="channel"
      6     )
----> 7 response = request.execute()
      8 response

File ~\pyenv\socialmining\Lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\_helpers.py:130, in positional.<locals>.positional_decorator.<locals>.positional_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    128     elif positional_parameters_enforcement == POSITIONAL_WARNING:
    129         logger.warning(message)
--> 130 return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\pyenv\socialmining\Lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py:938, in HttpRequest.execute(self, http, num_retries)
    936     callback(resp)
    937 if resp.status >= 300:
--> 938     raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
    939 return self.postproc(resp, content)

HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=5&q=pewdiepie&type=channel&key=AIzaSyBX-q53U3O7s61AtwOSegJsxG-ZtQvHiJE&alt=json returned "The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your <a href="/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota">quota</a>.". Details: "[{'message': 'The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your <a href="/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota">quota</a>.', 'domain': 'youtube.quota', 'reason': 'quotaExceeded'}]">
```

I am running jupyter in a virtual environment, still the teacher was also running it in a virtual environment and had no problem, as I said my quota is 0 on the API so I can't wrap my head around this.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about a problem triggered by server-side logic that nobody here (unless they're under a NDA with Google) is able to directly inspect or speak to; consequently, the question is entirely unanswerable.

Comment: It _might be interesting_ to know what other tools or software you use from the same Google account, and whether that includes anything trying to automate interaction with youtube -- which is all to say that the problem likely has nothing at all to do with your Python, and everything to do with other actions taken by the same Google account.

Comment: (Curious how you came to the conclusion that your "quota is 0" -- Google generally doesn't _offer_ unlimited quotas at all, and only lifts the 10,000/day default limit when a human on their staff has performed a manual audit).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently when I went to enable the api I also enabled all other services, after disabling them everything worked, don't have a single clue how i managed to do that.